# Can't create trigger in MySQL to make a simple audit

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have a table sales:

```sql
Create table sales ( sales_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, 
                     customer_id BIGINT, 
                     sales_amount DOUBLE ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Then to audit this:

```
Create table audit_log ( log_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                         sales_id BIGINT, 
                         previous_amount DOUBLE, 
                         new_amount DOUBLE ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

And I've tried for many, many ways of make this trigger:

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER log_sales_updates
AFTER UPDATE
ON sales
FOR EACH ROW
Insert into audit_log(sales_id, previous_amount, new_amount) VALUES (NEW.sales_id,OLD.sales_amount, NEW.sales_amount)//
DELIMITER ;
```

The output I've for this is: (nothing) I other words the prompt disapeear, I change for this:
[image: output]
I tried with semicolon after insert but the result is the same the prompt disapeear, I have to quit with Ctrl+C

- I'm using MySQL 8.0.19 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`;` at the end of INSERT statement is lost.

Use

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_sales_updates
AFTER UPDATE
ON sales
FOR EACH ROW
Insert into audit_log ( sales_id,     previous_amount,  new_amount) 
VALUES                ( NEW.sales_id, OLD.sales_amount, NEW.sales_amount) ;
```

DELIMITER reassign is excess for single-statement trigger.